# AJAX request results in 'undefined is not an object' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, undefined

My function works correctly, in that data is correctly requested via AJAX and displayed as appropriate, however the following error is also being thrown:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'obj[i].title')
```

My function is as follows:

```
function populateNews(obj) {
    var article = $('article p');
    article.each(function(i) {
        $(this).html('<p>'+obj[i].title+'</p>');
    });
}
```

I'm failing to understand how to resolve the error. `populateNews(obj)` is being called from a deferred AJAX request via `.done()`; have read similar posts that allude to this potentially being the issue, but no answer seems to fit my particular scenario.

Comment: what is the relationship between obj and artical? while you iterating article access obj.. probably obj is not a array or length is lesser than requesting indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to have the `for` loop.... the error just means that `obj`'s length is less than the length of `article`

```
function populateNews(obj) {
    var article = $('article p');
    //no need to have the for loop
    article.each(function (i) {
        //if obj[i] is not there update it with empty content
        $(this).html('<p>' + (obj[i] ? obj[i].title : '') + '</p>');
    });
}
```